# How can connect psql with normal user without specifying database name?

Tags: postgresql

I can connect mysql with username without specifying any database name,`showkey` is one of mysql user:

```
mysql -u showkey -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 14
Server version: 10.3.31-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 Debian 10
```

Now i log into mysql without specifying any database name.`showkey` is also a normal user for my postgresql,`test` is a database name in my postgresql.

```
psql -d test -U showkey
Timing is on.
Pager usage is off.
Null display is "missing data".
psql (11.14 (Debian 11.14-0+deb10u1))
Type "help" for help.

test=#
```

I conncet the `test` database with a normal user `showkey`,now want to connect postgresql with normal user without specifying database name such way as in mysql:

```
psql -U showkey
psql: FATAL:  database "showkey" does not exist
```

`sudo -u postgres psql` can connect postgresql with a super user instead of with normal user.

Comment: There is no "default" database in Postgres. You always have to specify one. The two options you have: use `-d test` or set the [environment variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html)  `PGDATABASE` for your operating system user.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That should be an answer.